# Why does my template lead to duplicated symbols?

Tags: c++, templates, enums

My program has 30 duplicate symbols errors for the methods `length()` and `table()` from the `struct` below.

This struct can be instantiated in four ways. Each of them is identical but for the table each instantiation refers to and, potentially, the length of that table.

This needs to be known at compile time in order that I can construct an array in the following fashion.

`std::array<BandlimitedOscillator<SAW>, N> oscillators;`.

Could someone please help me to see my error?

```
/// \brief A set of constants to be used for the purpose of constructing a
/// bandlimited wavetable oscillator, as in `BandlimitedOscillator<WaveTableType>`

enum WaveTableType { SIN, SQR, TRI, SAW };

// ===================================================== //
// =============== Template declaration ================ //
// ===================================================== //

/// \brief A collection of bandlimited wavetables to be used with a BandlimitedOscillator.

template <WaveTableType W>
struct WaveTable
{
public:
    /// \brief Return the length of the wavetable.

    const int length();

    /// \brief Return a pointer to the selected wavetable

    const float * table();

    /// \brief Select the wavetable with the greatest number of
    /// overtones that won't produce aliasing at 44.1kHz.

    void select(const float frequency);

private:
    /// \brief The currently selected wavetable index

    int tableIndex = 0;
};

// ===================================================== //
// ============== Template implementation ============== //
// ===================================================== //

template <> const int WaveTable<SQR>::length() { return kSquareTableLength;   }

template <> const int WaveTable<TRI>::length() { return kTriangleTableLength; }

template <> const int WaveTable<SAW>::length() { return kSawtoothTableLength; }

template <> const float * WaveTable<SQR>::table()  { return &(wt_square[tableIndex][0]);   }

template <> const float * WaveTable<TRI>::table()  { return &(wt_triangle[tableIndex][0]); }

template <> const float * WaveTable<SAW>::table()  { return &(wt_sawtooth[tableIndex][0]); }

template <WaveTableType W>
void WaveTable<W>::select(const float frequency)
{
    if      (frequency > 10240.F) tableIndex = 9;
    else if (frequency > 5120.F ) tableIndex = 8;
    else if (frequency > 2560.F ) tableIndex = 7;
    else if (frequency > 1280.F ) tableIndex = 6;
    else if (frequency > 640.F  ) tableIndex = 5;
    else if (frequency > 320.F  ) tableIndex = 4;
    else if (frequency > 160.F  ) tableIndex = 3;
    else if (frequency > 80.F   ) tableIndex = 2;
    else if (frequency > 40.F   ) tableIndex = 1;
    else                          tableIndex = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fully specialized template functions in a header file should be declared inline

```
template <> inline const int WaveTable<SQR>::length() { return kSquareTableLength; }
            ^^^^^^
```

etc. etc.

Comment: Thanks, John! That solved my problem.